# How to combine the data provider in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I have one table with the history of the sold tickets, each ticket is a row with some properties.

To display the history, i use two tables with the same columns:

1. list sum of all tickets are grouped by month ($dataProviderAll)
2. list of all tickets for the current month ($dataProviderCurrent)

I use sqlDataProviders to display data from the database with the tickets and this is no problem.

**How do I merge $dataProviderAll and $dataProviderCurrent to show the united data in a one GridView?**

I needed that to load the united $dataProvider in kartik`s ExportMenu and make exports to excel.

I think about subquery in sqlDataProvider with UNION, but it is not like seems good,

Comment: can you add your code?. data providers?.

Comment: It is a standard dataProvider, you can see that at  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html

Answer (score 4):

```
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;

$data = array_merge($dataProviderAll->getModels(), $dataProviderCurrent->getModels());

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
  'allModels' => $data
]);
```